# Capture and check return status inline in if statement inside [[ ]]

Tags: bash

I'm refactoring my scripts and am trying to convert all `if cmd; then fi;` statements to `if [[cmd]]; then fi`. I know how to convert it by invoking the command in previous line and using its exit code in current line, but I want to know how to do it inline.

Example:

```sh
# I have this

if grep "some-string" some_file.txt > /dev/null; then
  echo "non zero exit status"
fi
```

```sh
# I know how to do this

$(grep "some-string" some_file.txt > /dev/null)
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  echo "non zero exit status"
fi
```

```sh
# I want to know how to do something like this?

if [[ grep "some-string" some_file > dev/null ]]; then
  echo "non zero exit status"
fi
```

Please let me know how to do inline execution and check of status code for a command inside `if [[...]]; then fi` statement?

I'm referencing bash from [this](https://devhints.io/bash) and trying to follow styling from [this](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html)

Comment: Don't. The `if grep ...` version you have now is correct and idiomatic. You use `[[ ]]` when you want to test a conditional expression, not when you want to see whether a command succeeded (unless you stored the exit status of the command in a variable, in which case you need a conditional expression to check the value of the variable).

Comment: What?! `[[ grep ...` doesn’t make any sense. `if grep ...` is the correct way to do it. What part of that style guide makes you think that you need to refactor it?

Comment: (OT: The refactoring that code needs it removing `> /dev/null` and adding `-q`.)

Comment: @Biffen [this part in the style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s6.3-tests) is what was confusing me. I'm not that versed in shell-scripting as I'm using shell. The `-q` flag for grep is helpful though.

Comment: @rsampaths16 That section does not apply to commands’ exit codes. It just says to use `[[` over `test` (and other ways to call `test`, e.g. `[`). You’re not using `test`, so the rule doesn’t apply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not make sense:

```
if cmd ; ...
```

would run `cmd` and then branch depending on the exit status of cmd.

Similarily,

```
if [[ cmd ]]; ....
```

runs the command [[...]] and branch accordingly. It does not run `cmd`.

Actually, as long as you are only interested in knowing whether the exit status is zero or not, I see no reason why you should fiddle around with `$?`. Things are different if you have several exit status values to distinguish. For example:

```
grep foo bar; status=$?
if (( status == 0 ))
then
   # actions where grep found the pattern
elif (( status == 1 ))
   # actions where grep did not find the pattern
else
   # actions where grep encountered a serious problem
fi
```

In this case, store the exit code immediately after invoking your command into some variable, and process it later with `if` or `case` or whatever you need.